# how to make a custom list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to makeit look like as shown
I make 80 % of the list but it doesn't look like the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/3kHn9/

```
var name = new Array();
name[0] = "10000";
name[1] = "20750";
name[2] = "80485";
name[3] = "41185";
name[4] = "78596";

var address = new Array();
address[0] = "Ammer Computer GmbH";
address[1] = "c-entron software gmbh"; 
address[2] = "Computersysteme Mayer";
address[3] = "Fischer Pc";
address[4] = "Kaisher IT systemeAG";

$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        $('#folderData').append('<li class="rowclick" id="'+i+'"><p>'+name[i]+'</p><p>'+address[i]+'</p></li>');
    }

    // Refreshing the list
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update some css.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/3kHn9/5/

#### CSS

```
#folderData {
    float:left;
    margin:2%;
    width:96%;
}
#folderData li {
    margin:10px 0px;
    border :1px solid #ddd;            
    background:#fff url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/transparent/png/24x24/001_15.png) no-repeat right center;
}
```